# insertion only in table with one auto_increment column

Tags: mysql

is possible make insert in the table with only one column and this column is primary and auto_increment.
exactly what I want is increase id by one and write it to table ... is it possible without select max value and increase it by one and than insert..  I think direct insert just increment value

Comment: I just have to ask: why do you want such a thing? What's the point of the id if there's no associated data?

Comment: there are another table with more option for each id -> example title but multi languages, I can put another data to this table but in this case I need just Id, and It si ineteresting question to know it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: `INSERT INTO foo (id) VALUES ('')`

This will add a new entry, and the id will auto-increment with 1 each time.
If this is useful is another question.. :-)

Answer (score 5):

The following statements will all cause an auto-increment column in MySQL to generate a new value:

```
INSERT INTO Foo (id) VALUES (0);
INSERT INTO Foo (id) VALUES (''); -- because the integer value of '' is zero
INSERT INTO Foo (id) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO Foo (id) VALUES (DEFAULT);
INSERT INTO Foo () VALUES ();
```